# Using LINQ-to-objects to create a DataTable from a collection

Tags: vb.net, datatable, linq-to-objects

In my VB.NET code, I have something like this:
A collection of `clsEmployees`, which is made up of `clsEmployee` objects.

I would need a LINQ statement, such that it would return me a DataTable, made up of rows of fields of `clsEmployee`, which are supposedly firstname, lastname, employeeID, phone, city etc.

Also, the LINQ statement should return only those rows where phone is not null.

Comment: What have you tried already that didn't work?  The site is for helping others solve problems, not do their work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var aList = empList
             .Where((e) => e.phone != null)
             .Select((e) => new { firstname : e.firstname, lastname : e.lastname });  // etc
```

If you really need rows you can use new DataRow(...) in the select.